# Android - tab functionality implementation using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Actually i implemented the tabs functionality using Fragments. My app having the 3 tabs. At the time of tab creation i set the one fragment for each tab. Suppose currently we are in first fragment of first tab. We have a navigation from the first fragment to some other fragments(Means Fragment1-->Fragment2-->fragment3 within the single tab). Now we are in third fragment of First tab. In this case I clicked on Second tab and come back to the First tab. Here i should show the 3rd Fragment like tabs but i shows the Fragment1. Please help me how to show the recent one. please see my [code](http://pastie.org/7951621).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding code below in `OnCreate()` :

```
  if (savedInstanceState != null)
  {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); 
   //set the tab as per the saved state
   }
```

And in `OnSaveInstanceState` do this :

```
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```